# Laravel 4, messy Eloquent join query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on somehow messy project where structure of db is:

```
Object
id, title, description, url ... [and some more columns]

ObjectMeta
object_id, variable, value
```

So let's give you:

```
Object: 1, 'Cool Book', 'This cool book is just for you!', ...

Object Meta:
1, 'author_name', 'John Doe'
1, 'released', 2014
1, 'price', 23.22
1, 'url', 'http://amazon.com/coolbook'
1, 'genre', 3
```

So I need to perform query which will:

Pull all Objects that has genre 3, then sort those Objects by their released date.

```
$objs = static::Active()
->where('object', '=', $object)
->where('category','=',$category)
->whereIn('site_id', array(self::$site_id, 0))
->leftJoin('object_meta', function($join)
{
  $join->on('object.id','=', 'object_meta.content_id');
})
->where('object_meta.variable', 'genre')
->where('object_meta.value', 3);
->where('object_meta.variable', 'released');
->orderBy('object_meta.value', 'desc');
->groupBy('object.id')
->paginate(20);
```

This query has 0 results even if there are plenty of those books out there. I know that the second object_meta.variable where is guilty here. How can I write this query to make it work?

Really appreciating your help.

-- Edit

I've created workaround but it's really, really bad workaround (funny thing is that I swear the query above was working for month or so).

```
$objs = static::Active()
->where('object', '=', $object)
->where('category','=',$category)
->whereIn('site_id', array(self::$site_id, 0))
->leftJoin('object_meta', function($join)
{
  $join->on('object.id','=', 'object_meta.content_id');
})
->where('object_meta.variable', 'genre')
->where('object_meta.value', 3);
->groupBy('object.id')
->get();

foreach($objs as $obj)
{
  $obj->id = $obj->object_id;
    $objs_meta = ObjectMeta::where('object_id',$obj->object_id)->get();
    foreach($objs_meta as $obj_meta)
    {
      $variable = $obj_meta->var;
      $obj->$variable = $obj_meta->value;
    }
}
$objs = $objs->sortBy(function($role){
  return $role->released;
});
$objs = Paginator::make($objs->toArray(), sizeof($objs), $limit);
```

Comment: With `->where('object_meta.variable', 'released');` you're trying to find a column where `variable` is equal to both `genre` AND `released`? This is likely why its returning 0 rows.

Comment: The first thing that you should do with debugging a queries is to look at the `DB::getQueryLog()` log, what queries are being built. You can also you ->toSql() and run that query directly against the database, using i.e. console.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that issue. Queries don't work when run against database via console. The thing I really want is to somehow inject the "META.VAR" and "META.VALUE" information into my "OBJECT". So I'll be able to directly call for object.released, object.author, object.url and I will get "META.VALUE" as an result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need inner join (`join()`) not `leftJoin()`, and you need it twice:

```
$objs = static::Active()
 ->where('object', '=', $object)
 ->where('category','=',$category)
 ->whereIn('site_id', array(self::$site_id, 0))

 ->join('object_meta as genre', function ($join) {
   $join->on('object.id', '=', 'genre.content_id')
      ->where('genre.variable', '=', 'genre')
      ->where('genre.value', '=', 3);
 })
 ->join('object_meta as released', function ($join) {
   $join->on('object.id', '=', 'released.content_id')
      ->where('released.variable', '=', 'released');
 })

 ->orderBy('released.value', 'desc');
 ->select('object.*', 'released.value as released')

 ->distinct()
 // or group by, doesn't matter in your case
 // ->groupBy('object.id')

 ->paginate(20);
```

Then your objects will have additional property `released` with appropriate value.

---

According to the comments:

If you want to dynamically add the joins, then I suggest scopes like below:

```
public function scopeGenre($query, $value)
{
   $query->join('object_meta as genre', function ($join) use ($value) {
       $join->on('object.id', '=', 'genre.content_id')
          ->where('genre.variable', '=', 'genre')
          ->where('genre.value', '=', $value);
     });
}
```

then:

```
$query->where(..)->genre(3)->...
```

Comment: That's what I wanted! PS. Is there a way to include X variables (basically, every MetaObject) in X joins so I'll be able to use all additional properties? User can define variables like 'genre', 'released'.

Comment: You mean like dynamic number of those joins?

Comment: Yes. Basically, Books have around 6 MetaObjects (genre, url, price, etc.) while Music or Videos have more of those (around 10). I can manually add join whenever I need it but query for pulling all MetaObject would be nice. Using your code I'll be able to use genre.value and released.value, but where it comes to url.value, I'll need to do another join.

Comment: Please don't mind it anymore! After working at this join issue for 3 hours I wasn't able to think properly. Solved it with simply foreach and using parameters -> http://pastebin.com/Na7tgckT